# ASP.NET MVC RenderAction re-renders whole page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

How do I prevent renderaction from rendering the masterpage and giving it back to me? I only want it to render 1 section, for eg.

The controller

```
public ActionResult PaymentOptions()
{
    return View(settingService.GetPaymentBanks().ToList());
}
```

The PaymentOptions View:

```
@model IEnumerable<Econo.Domain.PaymentBank>

<h2>Payments</h2>
<!-- Stuff here -->
```

The View

```
<div class="grid_10">

</div>

<div class="grid_14">
@{Html.RenderAction("PaymentOptions", "Administrator");}
</div>
```

In grid_14, the header, footer and everything else gets rendered. Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: so you want to refresh part of a page? thats what ajax is for.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
public ActionResult PaymentOptions()
{    
    return PartialView(settingService.GetPaymentBanks().ToList());
}
```

In Razor, partial views and full views have the same extension, so you need to explicitly use the PartialViewResult result type to specify a partial view.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
return View(settingService.GetPaymentBanks().ToList());
```

Has to use the overload so you can specify a master:

```
return View("PaymentOptions", "", settingService.GetPaymentBanks().ToList());
```

Comment: Is there a way to check if it was called by a RenderPartial so I can also render the page with the master and without the master if not renderpartial?